# How do I print a number n times in python?

Tags: python, printing, numbers, repeat

How do I print a number n times in Python?

I can print 'A' 5 times like this:

`print('A' * 5)
AAAAA`

but not 10, like this:

`print(10 * 5)
50`

I want the answer to be 
`10 10 10 10 10`

How do I escape the mathematical operation in `print()`?

I am not asking how to print the *string* '10' n times, I am asking how to print the *number* 10 n times.

Comment: Figured it out: `print([10] * 5)`

Comment: This is producing a list, whereas your expected output is a string. The correct answer is the one you can see in all the answers to your question..

Comment: R and Python are different @GaryNapier, you would  need to ensure whatever you want to repeatedly print via * operator is a string :)

Comment: I don't recommend using the * operand. It saves you a few lines, but is less clear than a basic loop.

Shortcuts often increase the chance for hidden bugs and code that is harder for others to read. For example, if you skip through your code in the future, you might just as easily see that * and assume the output is 50, instead of 10 10 10 10 10

Answer (score 4):

`10*5` actually does multiplication and ends up giving you 50, but when you do `'10 '*5`, the `*` operator performs the repetition operator, as you see in `'A' * 5` for example

```
print('10 ' * 5)
```

Output will be `10 10 10 10 10`

Or you can explicitly convert the int to a string via `str(num)` and perform the print operation

```
print((str(10)+' ') * 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the number as a variable:

```
number = 10
print("f{number} " * 5)
```

Or without f-strings:

```
number = 10
print((str(number)) + ' ') * 5)
```

If you just want to print a number many times, just handle it as as string:

```
print("10 " * 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This trick only works for strings.

```
print('10' * 5)
```

Will print:

```
1010101010
```

That's because the `*` operator is overloaded for the `str` class to perform string repetition.